# Safe way to stop/abort REINDEX

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am running a `REINDEX` but it takes long time and still working.  The application using the DB is not responding right now. Is there a safe way to stop it and do it another time?
PostgreSQL version is 8.4.

Comment: I would not expect any problem stopping a `REINDEX`.  Once it started, the index would be unusable until REINDEX successfully would finish.  But I'm concerned more with why do you need reindexing?  Anyhow, dropping the index and building it with `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` wouldn't block the normal operation of your system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. Might take a while, though.

In future you might want to use "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY", like dezso suggested, but first create new index, and then drop old one.

Comment: is there any script to automatically do the job ? as simple as just create a cron for it ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but since it's just two commands, you can write the commands in "recreate.sql" file, and now you have a script.