# How to restore a pg_dumpall dump without CREATE INDEX?

Tags: postgresql, index, migration, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10

I am attempting to migrate from Postgres 9.6 to 10.3 and during the restore each index is recreated one by one - this is a problem.

So far I thought `pg_dumpall` is a good option.

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 --clean --file=dumpall_clean.sql
```

Once this is done the file is around 1.2TB in size and I can load it to the new 10.3 instance with

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5433 < dumpall_clean.sql
```

simple.

**Problem**

As I learned [the indicies are not backed up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123788/47647) like tables are, they are simply recreated, and that is my problem.

The cluster has thousands of partitions each with several million rows and two indices (one BTREE and one GIST). This takes day*s* since each index is created one by one.

As I have enough resources and I know which indices have to be created, I would perfer to do this step after the dump has been restored. Initially I made 8 FOR loops (to run in parallel) to go through the partitions, and created an index by moving a partition to a faster tablespace (SSD), create the index, then move the table and the index back to the default tablespace. So far this has worked for me.

**Question**
How can I have the same result* of a `pg_dumpall` dump without recreating the indices when loading the `dumpall_clean.sql` file? 
A `pg_dumpall --without-index` would be nice.

> "This currently includes information about database users and groups, tablespaces, and properties such as access permissions that apply to databases as a whole." - [pg_dumpall manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-dumpall.html)

Comment: Are the two Postgres installations on the same server? If yes, you could use `pg_upgrade` with the `--link` option which will massively increase the speed of the migration

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, two separate machines.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since this was up, but we need do something like this in our restores.  Finding this answer has actually made me realize I can use something just like this to speed up my current restore by cutting out the index creation :)

You can use the -l and -L flags to pg_restore to list actions and use a list of actions.

From my notes in our script:

```
    # pg_restore -l gives a list of all operations that would be performed during the restore.
    # pg_restore -L accepts a list of operations from file to perform during the restore.
```

So you can use -l to dump the list of operations from an existing dump, filter it, and then run again w/ -L to accept that newly filtered list of operations.

In practice that looks something like:

```
    ${PGRESTORE} --dbname=db_restore -Fc -l dump_filename \
        | grep -v "public view_we_dont_want" \
        | grep -v "public postgres" >${tmpFile}
    ${PGRESTORE} --dbname=db_restore -Fc -L ${tmpFile} dump_filename
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see one workaround for this, by using `pg_dumpall` in two steps:

```
pg_dumpall --schema-only ....
```

Then edit the file and extract the index definitions into a second file. You also need to extract the foreign keys, because you have to run them manually after the import (probably together with the index creation script)

Then run that script (without the indexes) to create the (empty) tables. You

```
pg_dumpall --data-only ....
```

Then run that script to import the data into the new database. After that run the FK and index creation scripts.

Comment: Thanks! Couple of questions; As I also need the roles and tablespaces, should I do ```pg_dumpall --globals-only ... --file=globals.sql```, ```pg_dumpall --schema-only ... --file=schema.sql```, and then ```pg_dumpall --data-only ... --file=data.sql```? Then I can edit the ```schema.sql``` as you suggested and run (in this order?) ```globals.sql```, ```schema.sql```,```data.sql```, and then the index creation the way I want it? I am also thinking of using ```grep``` to find the lines with ```CREATE INDEX```, write a new file and commenting them in the orginal ```*.sql``` dump using ```sed```.

Comment: @Michael: yes you would need globals as well. I was just focusing on the basic idea to separate the generation of the DDL from the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

**Before Upgrade;**

Dump globals;

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only --file=globals.sql
```

Dump pre-data;

```
pg_dump --format=plain --create --section=pre-data --file=pre-data.sql db_name
```

Dump post-data;

```
pg_dump --format=custom --section=post-data --file=post-data.custom db_name
pg_dump --format=plain --section=post-data --file=post-data.sql db_name
```

Restore globals, pre-data, "grant" section of post-data (extract it from `post-data.sql` using text editor)

```
psql --file=globals.sql
psql --file=pre-data.sql
psql --file=post-data-permissions.sql db_name
```

**Cut for upgrade...**

Dump data;

```
pg_dump --format=directory --jobs=8 --section=data --compress=9 --file=data.d db_name
```

Restore data;

```
pg_restore --jobs=8 --dbname=db_name data.d
```

--> now db is ready for connection (and its slow of course)

Restore indexes fkeys and grants (yeah again but its ok)

```
pg_restore --jobs=8 --dbname=db_name post-data.custom
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible to just filter them out using "grep" :

```
grep -v '^CREATE INDEX [^\t]*;$'  dump.sql | psql
```

or

```
pg_dumpall "source db connection string"  | \
grep -v '^CREATE INDEX [^\t]*;$'          | \
psql "destination db connection string"
```

should be safe unless you have matching lines inside stored code.

in your specific case:

```
grep -v '^CREATE INDEX [^\t]*;$' dumpall_clean.sql | psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5433
```

Comment: yes something like this is what I was thinking about, too. Since, there are procedures that contain the ```CREATE INDEX``` statement, I just have to match those lines a bit better.

Comment: perhaps you can find those procedures and modify the lines so that they start with a space or tab or end with a comment or space etc . then they won't match that regex.

Comment: there's probably an SQL update you could run to do that :)

Comment: `update pg_catalog.pg_proc as p set prosrc= regexp_replace(prosrc,'CREATE INDEX ',' CREATE INDEX ','g')  where p.prolang = ( select oid from  pg_catalog.pg_language  where lanname='plpgsql' ); `